# Error con interface de projecto

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, iis

Buens, alguno tiene idea de porque la inteface grafica de un projecto puede cambiar drasticamente cuando se sube al IIS7 (windows y), tengo un projecto y cuando lo ejecuto localmente todo bien, pero en el IIS la interfaz cambia y algunas funciones tambien dejan de servir.
AYUDA, GRACIAS

VERSION SERVIDOR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

VERSION LOCALMENTE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si las librerías de css están cargando adecuadamente, a mi parecer el detalle va por ahí...

Comment: viste los logs que arroja en el servidor?

Comment: Apenas empiezo en esto, el servidor no envía ninguna notificación o warning sobre algo, solamente que por ejemplo al ingresar mis credenciales deberia dejarme iniciar sesión y lo que hace es intentar cargar y muestra la misma pagina, la que ven arriba. Alguno sabe como debuguear en IIS7? Xq el problema es precisamente cuando lo publico, Si lo ejecuto localmente el funciona perfecto. Para iniciar sesión hace uso de Active Directory, lo revisa, si existe el user ahí, permite iniciar sesión.

Comment: Como te ha dicho @EdGarcía, el problema tiene pinta de estar relacionado con los css. Busca en tu proyecto local archivos con extension .css, mira en que carpeta estan situados, y tienes que replicarlos en la misma ruta en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Si el problema se relaciona con la autenticacion recuerda que los recursos como .css o .js no se podran acceder hasta tanto no estes autenticado

Es por eso que se usa el `<location>` en el web.config para habilitar el acceso a estos archivos aunque no estes autenticado

```
<location path="carpetaStyle">      
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

la idea es que indiques el nombre de la carpeta o el archivo que quieres permitir el acceso

[Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)

Tambien recomendaria que habilites el Developer Tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, y analices la solapa "Network" para ver quer archivos carga y si el css que defiens los estilos esta fallando cuando resuelve la ruta

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. Ya hice lo que indicaste y el problema sigue igual.

Comment: <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"></allow>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Client Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"></allow>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"></allow>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>

Comment: Usé lo anterior basado en el post que agragaste y el problema sigue igual.